# Парсинг пайтона, как скачать всю страницу

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Есть многие сайты где что бы посмотреть весь контент нужно пролистать в низ, и он сгенерируется. Как сделать так на пайтоне что бы можно было бы скачать всю страницу с подгружаемом контентом. Пример такой страницы, все записи сообщества в вк

Comment: Изучить движок сайта, посмотреть каким именно образом он получает данные (наверняка делает через ajax какие то api вызовы к своему серверу). Написать на питоне эмулятор таких запросов к API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой способ это имитировать работу обычного браузера. Сделать это можно посредством любого headless browser. И затем, обратившись к объекту windows страницы проскролить вниз.
Как headless browser можно использовать Selenium WebDriver для Python.
Код будет выглядеть примерно так (я его не проверял)

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com");
driver.execute_script('window.scrollBy(0, 10000000);')
```

Подробнее, читайте доки по библиотеке [тут](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage)